# What XPATH I need to extract the text inside SPAN that is preceded by a specific label inside a STRONG, both inside a P?

Tags: xpath, extract, import.io

What XPATH I need to extract the text inside SPAN that is preceded by a specific label inside a STRONG, both inside a P?

For example to extract website and email addresses from a page that looks like this:

```
<p>
<strong>Website:</strong>
<span>www.example.com</span>
</p>
<p>
<strong>Contact email:</strong>
<span>email@example.com</span>
</p>
```

Comment: can you share a little more of the html or the actual link - I cant see what the class of any preceding tags are so its difficult to give an answer

Comment: Last time I posted a link, and I got my question on hold and later deleted, community thinking that I am posting to advertise a page.

Answer (score 1):

This shall do:

```
//p/span[preceding::*[1][self::strong and . = 'Contact email:']]
```

Here, you are selecting all `p/span` elements with first preceding element `strong`, where label is `Contact email:`

Answer (score 0):

Website:

```
//p/span[preceding::strong[1]/text()='Website:']
```

Email:

```
//p/span[preceding::strong[1]/text()='Contact email:']
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also important to note that, by using `preceding` axes as shown in the other two answers, the XPath will mistakenly return `span` element that is formed like the following :

```
<strong>Website:</strong>
<p>
<span>www.example.com</span>
</p>
```

You can use `preceding-sibling` axes instead to avoid the mistake mentioned above :

```
//p/span[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::strong and . = 'Website:']]
```

`preceding-sibling` axes only consider elements that is located before *context element* (the `span` in this case), and is *sibling* (share the same parent) of the context element.